# aspnet JIT compilation killing the servers

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, asp.net

I have Win2012-IIS servers hosting ~25 aspnet/c# webapps each, and there is a performance problem with the aspnet JIT/just-in-time compiling.

When the JIT operation starts automatically, after a code deploy, it brings the machines to crawl. We also discovered that sometimes randomly it loops forever(eating all cpu).
The problem started small but it's become worse with increasing number of apps per server and complexity of the program.
The deploys happen during work hours and we already had one major service outage thanks to lenghty or hanged post-deploy JIT processes that killed 2 machines.

The apps are all the same product, but they use different DBs, domains and code versions. The developers deploy new code builds quite often, by copying the .Dll and other files in the app directories.
The machines have top-tier Xeon-E3 or i7-4x/6x cpus, and just enough ram to run all the apps which take ~700megs each.